# Maximum performance configuration for a release build VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to know the optimum performance configuration  I can obtain for a release build. I do not need any debugging info in a release build and if omitting it helps boost performance in a release build I am more than happy to abide by those changes.
Kindly let me know if these setting are acceptable or if any of these settings should be changed for better performance.This is the configuration I have

> Build Type : Release
>
> Debug Information Format : Program Database (/Zi)
>
> Preprocesors : Following are the preprocessors
>
> WIN32 QT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT QT_DLL QT_NO_DEBUG NDEBUG QT_CORE_LIB
>   QT_GUI_LIB
>
> Generate Debug Info : Yes (/Debug)
>
> Optimization : Maximize Speed (/O2)
>
> Whole Program Optimization : No

Overview of entire configuration

> /I".\GeneratedFiles" /I"." /I"C:\Qt\4.8.4\include"
>   /I".\GeneratedFiles\Release" /I"C:\Qt\4.8.4\include\QtCore"
>   /I"C:\Qt\4.8.4\include\QtGui"
>   /I"....\External\boost-win-1.47-32bit-vs2010\include\boost-1_47"
>   /I"....\External\ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc\ta-lib\c\include\"
>   /I"....\External\Qpid-32Bit\Debug\include\" /I"..\Common\"
>   /I"....\External\log4cplus-1.1.2-rc1\include" /Zi /nologo /W1 /WX-
>   /O2 /Oy- /D "WIN32" /D "QT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT" /D "QT_DLL" /D
>   "QT_NO_DEBUG" /D "NDEBUG" /D "QT_CORE_LIB" /D "QT_GUI_LIB" /Gm- /EHsc
>   /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t- /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\WOPR.pch"
>   /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze-
>   /errorReport:queue

Should any of the above options be changed inorder to obtain maximum runtime performance.
If I have omitted any options kindly let me know.

Comment: `Whole Program Optimization : Yes` ?

Comment: So do I also have to enable Link Time Code Generation when I set whole program optimization to Yes? If so what should the Link Time Code Generation be ?

Comment: Yes, `/GL` for compilation, `/LTCG` for linker. However, there is no guarantee that this will do any good for your program. The best is to have a well-defined suite of benchmarks in your program, and to try several optimization options.

Comment: I think you mean /LTCG ?

Comment: Yes, fixed it in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the most optimized code from your compiler, you can try a *profile guided optimization* of your critical code. However, this kind of optimization is not as easy to achieve than simply tweaking to compiler options.

The achieve this, you will need to have a suite of tests that represents real-life scenarios. Instrument you code, run theses tests, and then:

- The instrumentation data will tell you *where* you spend most of your CPU time. Try to optimize (by hand) the parts of your code that seems to take a lot of CPU.
- Compile again your critical code with the instrumentation data as input.

I have never used this with Visual Studio (only Intel Compilers). VS2010 [seems to have profile-guide optimization features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e7k32f4k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).